# Detect start of a phone call to send JSON in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-telephony

There are phone numbers and user can tap on one of them to make a call. When the call is successfully connected, the app should send a `JSON` to my server.

I have a problem - as soon as a phone number is tapped, the `Phone` app pops up and my app is sent to background. I've read the `CoreTelephony Framework` docs and `CTCall` class reference but I'm not sure what these four statuses are:

```
extern NSString const *CTCallStateDialing;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateIncoming;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateConnected;
extern NSString const *CTCallStateDisconnected;
```

Are they checked in the background or while the `Phone` app is running. How to detect it?

Should I use **`applicationDidEnterBackground`**  method and `CTCall` class in it to fire a `JSON`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should go for **`CTCallCenter`** and implement a **`callEventHandler`** that will be fired when the call status changes. Here is how to do it.

First, you will need a `CTCallCenter` instance:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter *callCenter;
```

Then, set a callEventHandler when your app launches.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
        _callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

        [_callCenter setCallEventHandler:^(CTCall *call)
         {             
             if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected])
             {
                 NSLog(@"Connected");
             }
             else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing])
             {
                 NSLog(@"Dialing");
             }
             else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected])
             {
                 NSLog(@"Disconnected");

             } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming])
             {
                 NSLog(@"Incoming");
             }
         }];  

    return YES;
}
```

About the `callEventHandler`:

> This property’s block object is dispatched on the default priority
>   global dispatch queue when a call changes state. To handle such call
>   events, define a handler block in your application and assign it to
>   this property. You must implement the handler block to support being
>   invoked from any context.

Source: [CTCallCenter Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried it but the event handler seems not responding when the app is sleeping in the background when calling.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Nope... im doing more testing... I will leave a comment for other people if this works :)

Comment: @Raccoon I have just double checked, created a new iPhone project and used the code I posted and it works for me.

Comment: So you are able to get the events even if the app is in Background? For some reason sometimes it works and sometimes not in my project...

Comment: On iOS 7.0, After calling a number from application, app will enter in background state and after entering in foreground, block code is not executing. but everything is working fine on iOS 8.0.